# WinForm using webview2 with SSO

Tags: winforms, single-sign-on, webview2

I have a client application that hosts a web browser control (WebView2). The client application is configured to use SSO so the current windows user is automatically logged-in to the application. When I navigate to a web application on our intranet I want the current windows user's credentials to be used to automatically login to the web application (which support integrated windows authentication IWA) in the browser control.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You might try enabling the [CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions.AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environmentoptions.allowsinglesignonusingosprimaryaccount?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions_AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount) property. This will require creating a custom CoreWebView2Environment via [CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environment.createasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44) and then using [WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44) initialize your WebView2 using your custom CoreWebView2Environment. Be sure to call EnsureCoreWebView2Async before setting the WebView2.Source property as the Source property will implicitly initialize the WebView2 using a default CoreWebView2Environment.

Comment: A code sample would have been more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my demo project code based on the David his answer

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var browser = new WebView2();

        var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
        options.AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount = true;

        var environtment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(options: options).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environtment).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
        {
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlBrowser.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Source = new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/mail/");
        }));
    }
```